# Django Developments Template_DIRS setting failed

Tags: python, django, templates

I was recently trying to learn Django for one of my private project.
When came to the Chapter on Template,the Django Book recommended setting template path in settings.py using the the following snippet

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'templates').replace('\\','/'),)
```

However ,when I opened the file setting.py I found nothing like "TEMPLATE_DIR" but a list:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates').replace('\\','/'),],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

the the value related to the key "DIR",was a empty list. So I try to filled it with the content shown above.

And then, code something in the views.py(all the import was done )

```
def current_datetime(request):
  now = datetime.datetime.now()
  t = get_template("current_datetime.html")
  html = t.render(Context({"current_date" : now}))
  return HttpResponse(html)
```

And then mkdir templates in the same folder with setting.py , saved current_datetime.html in folder templates

Finally,run the project.and got the message in my terminal:

> WARNINGS:
> ?: (1_8.W001) The standalone TEMPLATE_* settings were deprecated in Django 1.8 > and the TEMPLATES dictionary takes precedence. You must put the values of the > following settings into your default TEMPLATES dict: TEMPLATE_DIRS.
>
> System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
> June 15, 2017 - 15:32:49
> Django version 1.11.2, using settings 'mysite.settings'
> Starting development server at 127.0.0.1:8000/
> Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

When opened the address (127.0.0.1:8000/time/) in my Safari,here came the
error message:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2f1S.png)

Anyone help,please ??

Comment: browsed a lot but found merely nothing helped..

Comment: my django version ：（1.11.2, u"final",0 ）  my  python  version:2.7

Comment: I didn't see your error image at first, you should edit your post to correctly embed it or copy the text from it

Comment: If your book contains `TEMPLATE_DIRS` then it is out of date, and you should look for a different resource to learn Django. If a resource was written for anything before Django 1.8, then you'll have problems when you try to use it with Django 1.11.

Answer (score 0):

There is a warning on TEMPLATE_DIRS, for that just be sure you don't have `TEMPLATE_DIRS` variable in your settings.py and restart development server.

Then for the error, you are actually using a Context object instead of a dict, you should render the template using a useful shortcut https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#example

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def current_datetime(request):
  now = datetime.datetime.now()
  return render(request, "current_datetime.html", {
    'current_date' : now,
  })
```

Comment: @SebCorbin he has TEMPLATE dict that is no need to define specific TEMPLATE_DIRS

Answer (score 0):

I think you have BASE_DIR in settings.py for define location so use like below

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

DIRS should be like below

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),],
```